# Entity SetInitializer gets an SQL timeout

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, azure

Using Entity's visual designer I have created the most basic entity possible. I want to seed some sample data to a database I created which holds the schema for this basic entity on Azure. I want to use this db in an asp.net web form but when I go to seed the init data I get an SQL timeout error.

I am aware that when using entities Database.SetInitializer the seed operation is only called when the context is used so I forced the initialization. It seems to try yet I still get the timeout. I created a basic console application and wrote a test program to load some values into the table and it worked fine so I know it is not the connection to the DB, it is something to do with the Seeding.

Here is the actual error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

Context File

```
namespace SlowTest.DB
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class ModelContainer : DbContext
    {
        public ModelContainer()
            : base("name=ModelContainer")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Books> Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Entity Class

```
namespace SlowTest.DB
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Books
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Initializer

```
namespace SlowTest.DB
{
    public class Init : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ModelContainer>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ModelContainer context)
        {
            GetBooks().ForEach(c => context.Books.Add(c));
        }
        private static List<Books> GetBooks()
        {
            var B = new List<Books>
            {
                new Books{
                    BookId = 0,
                    Author = "Neville",
                },
                new Books{
                    BookId = 3,
                    Author = "Steve",
                },
            };
            return B;
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
namespace SlowTest
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            Database.SetInitializer<ModelContainer>(new Init());
            ModelContainer db = new ModelContainer();
            db.Database.Initialize(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is my web.config. Most of which is auto generated by visual studio or entity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SlowTest-20150812115338.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SlowTest-20150812115338;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DB.Model.csdl|res://*/DB.Model.ssdl|res://*/DB.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=uvic.database.windows.net;initial catalog=TrojanDB;persist security info=True;user id=nhoughto;password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
            ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The timeout could be a connection timeout. Are you using the right Web.config and how is configured the ModelContainer context in Web.config?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone stumbles here from Google... you need to increase your CommandTimeout to give Azure enough time to create the db.

There is an incredibly detailed StackOverlow answer explaining why here:
[Timeout when setting up Entity Framework connecting to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419297/timeout-when-setting-up-entity-framework-connecting-to-azure)

The gist of it is that you need to add a single line into your DbContext constructor:

```
public MyContext() : base("name=MyContext")
{
    // three minute command timeout
    this.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
}
```